# Parallel.ForEach local storage

Tags: vb.net, parallel-processing

I recently changed a For Each loop to a Parallel.ForEach loop. I'm concerned about an object being declared outside the loop but assigned while iterating in the loop. Here is the simplified code.

```
Dim results As ModelResults
Dim noResultsModel As New List(Of ModelResults)
Dim lock As New Object
Parallel.ForEach(_modelEngines,
    Sub(model)

    results = model.Execute

    If results IsNot Nothing Then

        SyncLock lock
            noResultsModel.Add(results)
        End SyncLock

    End If

    results = Nothing

End Sub)
```

Is there a potential race condition with the results object? Would anything be different if I moved the declaration of results into the for loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there definitely is a race condition with the variable declared outside the loop:

```
Thread 1: results = model.Execute ' results are from Thread1's current modelEngine
Thread 2: results = model.Execute ' results are from Thread2's current modelEngine
Thread 2: If results IsNot Nothing Then ' results are from Thread2's current modelEngine
Thread 1: If results IsNot Nothing Then ' results are from Thread2's current modelEngine(!)
```

Just move it inside, I don't see why you'd want to declare it outside the loop anyways.